# Execute ajax after counter is set to 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a PPC site. When timer counter is set to 0 code should automatically run query. If user close window and click again query should not trigger until again 30 secs are completed.

URL is set in database for users to visit with a column of hits. If hits are set to 0 or 1 by default (0) it will show. when a page is run it fetch record. Set two session of current URL & previous URL and update hits to 1. Both session are set similar initially. after thirty seconds when page loads again first current URL session is created ant it matches both session. If both session are different it will update hits to 2 by matching previous URL session and login ID.

Creating sessions of current URL and previous URL

```
$_SESSION['url']=$row['url'];
$_SESSION['previousURL']=$row['url'];
```

Javascript is used for timer

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
function checklength(i) {
    'use strict';
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

var minutes, seconds, count, counter, timer;
count = 30; //seconds
counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    'use strict';
    count = count - 1;
    minutes = checklength(Math.floor(count / 60));
    seconds = checklength(count - minutes * 60);
    if (count < 0) {

        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Next refresh in ' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ';
    if (count === 0) {

        location.reload();
    }
}
    </script>
```

Actual output what i am getting in this case is if timer wont complete and user close window than by clicking again it fetch previous URL and set hits to 2.

What expected is that update query should only trigger when timer gets completed.

Comment: HI and welcome to SO. It seems that the only way the "set hits to 2" can happen according to your description is if and only if `$_SESSION['url']` and `$_SESSION['prviousURL']` are different. If that is true, then we need to see the PHP as this seems like a server issue and not a client timer issue.

Comment: is there a way when in javascript counter is set to 0 ajax fires and execute query and unset session

Comment: No. Javascript cannot modify the session that is created by and controlled by server  code.

Comment: Sorry, yes, when the variable `count` reaches `0` you can make any call you like - including an AJAX request. Doing both an AJAX request and setting `document.location` is problematic and you should not do both.

Comment: Thanks this is what i am looking how to get it done

i want to fire it with before location.reload()

Comment: My suggestion, if you need to reload the page, is to make your AJAX request, then wait for the response. If the response signals success, THEN reload the page. If the AJAX is not successful, you'll have an opportunity to deal with the error. Otherwise you have no way to determine what will actually happen with the AJAX request.

Comment: i understand and agree to your point i am unable to create a code to fire ajax when count is set to 0 and then to get response of success and reload page. Can you please help me with code.

Comment: Here is a JSBin for you: https://jsbin.com/yipuhatuba/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for your help. It wasnt working, though today i learnt to believe yourself first. What i did is 
```
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = 'Next refresh in ' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ';
    if (count === 0) {
  $.ajax( {
   url:'adsUpdate.php',
   type:'POST',
   success: function(data) {
    window.location.reload();
   }
  });
    }
```